# Can an Azure YAML Pipelines deployment job type, have mutiple environment values?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-deployment

Is there any possibility to have mutiple values in the environment property of deployment jobs? Something similar to this example:

```
stages:
    - stage: 
      jobs:
          - deployment: 
            environment:  
              - environmentOne
              - environmentTwo
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                    - script: echo hello
```

[Micro doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#schema) do not make any allusion about that. I also found this [blog](https://blog.geralexgr.com/azure/target-multiple-environments-with-deployment-jobs-azure-devops), but for my case, the only porpuse of the environments is for the execution of the environment [approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simplified solution would be just to use the [each keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword) and object parameter to specify the environments.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default: 
  - environmentOne
  - environmentTwo

stages:
    - stage: 
      jobs:
      - ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
        - deployment: 
          environment: ${{ environment }}
          strategy:
            runOnce:
              deploy:
                steps:
                  - script: echo hello
```